# XPath - get element depending on its sub-element

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath, and using it in Java to fetch some data from website. Maybe you could help me or advice me what to use to accomplish what I want.

```
<a title="Person" href="some link">
 <name>John</name>
</a>
<a title="Person" href "some OTHER link">
 <name>Wayne</name>
</a>
```

How to get some attribute value of element  depending on its  sub-element?

For example, I need href value of element  that has sub-element  with value John, how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include the code you use in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an attribute:

```
//a/@href
```

Add a condition on the contents of the subtag:

```
//a[./name='John']/@href
```

Get the value of the attribute:

```
string(//a[./name='John']/@href)
```

Comment: Sorry for being nit-picking, `./` is not necessary because it is implicit. Shorten `a[./name='John']` to `a[name='John']`.